# Получить несколько значений по одному ключу в словаре

Tags: c#

Есть некий словарь:

```
Dictionary<string, string> AuthorList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
AuthorList.Add("aaa", "гистидин");
AuthorList.Add("bbb", "фенилаланин");
AuthorList.Add("aaa", "кокаин");
AuthorList.Add("ccc", "глицин");
AuthorList.Add("ddd", "глицин");
AuthorList.Add("aaa", "атропин");
```

Как мне по ключу aaa получить все значения (в виде списка или массива)?

Comment: Никак. У вас вас они просто не хранятся а перезатираются последним добавлением. Вам нужна другая структура данных для хранения списков

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а что вы предложите использовать, с возможностями словаря?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, например

Comment: @Ez Напишите пожалуйста в виде ответа как бы вы реализовали добавление в такой словарь несколько значений и вывод данных

Comment: Никак, потому что этот код вызывет ошибку выполнения на строчке `AuthorList.Add("aaa", "кокаин");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Почему не работает у вас

Так как ваш `AuthorList` имеет тип данных [Dictionary](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.9.php)<[string](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.1.php), string>, то он состоит из пар [KeyValuePair](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.8), где ключ - строка, и значение - строка. Таким образом, когда вы несколько раз записываете значения в ячейку с одним и тем же ключом, старое просто стирается (как в обычной [переменной](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.25.php)). Пример:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["Key1"] = "Value1";
Console.WriteLine(dict["Key1"]);
dict["Key1"] = "Value2";
Console.WriteLine(dict["Key1"]);
dict["Key1"] = "Value3";
Console.WriteLine(dict["Key1"]);
```

Вывод:

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

## Что делать?

Если вы хотите хранить сразу несколько значений для каждого ключа, ваш выбор - [List](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.5.php).

В таком случае словарь будет создаваться таким образом:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

*Конкретно* **вашу** задачу можно реализовать следующим образом:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> AuthorDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

AuthorDict["aaa"] = new List<string>();
AuthorDict["bbb"] = new List<string>();
AuthorDict["ccc"] = new List<string>();

AuthorList["aaa"].Add("гистидин");
AuthorList["bbb"].Add("фенилаланин");
AuthorList["aaa"].Add("кокаин");
AuthorList["ccc"].Add("глицин");
AuthorList["ddd"].Add("глицин");
AuthorList["ddd"].Add("атропин");
```

*В дальнейшем* вы можете обращаться к списку значений или к определенному значению по ключу следующим образом:

```
AuthorList["bbb"]; // Список по ключу "bbb"
AuthorList["aaa"][1]; // Первый элемент из списка по ключу "aaa"
```

## Дополнительно

В целом словарь представляет собой структуру [KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.8), то есть *и* ключом, *и* значением может быть вообще любой тип данных. Поэтому в зависимости от ваших желаний и целей, вы можете использовать и очереди [Queue](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.7.php), чтобы иметь возможности очередей, и хешсет [HashSet](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8), и **даже** другой словарь [Dictionary](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.9.php).
Например:

```
Dictionary<string, Queue<string>> QueuedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Queue<string>>();
Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> HashsetDictionary = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> DoubleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>();
```

Все это можно назвать List'ами с дополнительными особенностями, но т.к. вы в своем вопросе их не упоминали, на этом эту тему я остановлю

**P.S.** `Как мне по ключу aaa получить все значения (в виде списка или массива)?`   -   с массивом реализовать это будет сложно, так как его длина не динамична, поэтому могут возникнуть сложности с инициализацией или чтением...

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужен словарь, который по одному ключу может хранить несколько разных значений. Такие словари обычно называются как-то наподобие `MultiDictionary`.

К примеру, можно взять майкрософтовский [`MultiValueDictionary`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary/) из nuget-пакета [`Microsoft.Experimental.Collections`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/) (осторожно, он пре-релизный!). Подключите пакет (вам придётся поставить галку Include prerelease), и ваш код станет просто таким:

```cs
MultiValueDictionary<string, string> AuthorList = new();
AuthorList.Add("aaa", "гистидин");
AuthorList.Add("bbb", "фенилаланин");
AuthorList.Add("aaa", "кокаин");
AuthorList.Add("ccc", "глицин");
AuthorList.Add("ddd", "глицин");
AuthorList.Add("aaa", "атропин");

var results = AuthorList["aaa"];
foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

На консоли

> гистидин
> кокаин
> атропин

Comment: Интересный способ! А какие именно плюсы имеет данный способ перед словарем листов, т.е. `Dictionaty<string, List<string>>`? Это исключительно красота и простота кода (так как словарь списков даже звучит сложно) либо же здесь есть и определенная выгода в плане скорости/памяти и т.п.?

Comment: @МаксимФисман: С одной стороны, в `MultiValueDictionary` нет ничего такого, что нельзя было бы сделать руками. С другой стороны, `AuthorList["aaa"]` даёт `IReadOnlyCollection<string>`, чтобы никто не смог залезть и исправить список шаловливыми ручками. Впрочем, это наверное вкусовщина, главное — это более удобный интерфейс, а под капотом всё равно аналог `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` ([пруф](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/Microsoft/Collections/Extensions/MultiValueDictionary.cs#L38)).

Comment: @МаксимФисман: Ну и да, простота кода (что думаем, то и пишем, а не «`string` пишем, `List<string>` в уме») конечно важна.

Comment: Почему не `Lookup`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP: (1) Менее красиво: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QHX1Ro (2) `Lookup` не позволяет добавлять после создания, а ТС вроде хочет работать как со словарём.

Answer (score 2):

Значения для каждого ключа хранятся в List, поэтому могут повторяться:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> AuthorDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

AuthorDict["aaa"] = new List<string>();
AuthorDict["bbb"] = new List<string>();
AuthorDict["ccc"] = new List<string>();

AuthorDict["aaa"].Add("1");
AuthorDict["bbb"].Add("2");
AuthorDict["aaa"].Add("3");
AuthorDict["ccc"].Add("4");
AuthorDict["bbb"].Add("2");

foreach (var item in AuthorDict)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {String.Join(", ", item.Value)}");
```

Вывод:

```
aaa: 1, 3
bbb: 2, 2
ccc: 4
```

Значения для каждого ключа хранятся в HashSet, поэтому будут уникальными:

```
Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> AuthorDict = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

AuthorDict["aaa"] = new HashSet<string>();
AuthorDict["bbb"] = new HashSet<string>();
AuthorDict["ccc"] = new HashSet<string>();

AuthorDict["aaa"].Add("1");
AuthorDict["bbb"].Add("2");
AuthorDict["aaa"].Add("3");
AuthorDict["ccc"].Add("4");
AuthorDict["bbb"].Add("2");

foreach (var item in AuthorDict)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {String.Join(", ", item.Value)}");
```

Вывод:

```
aaa: 1, 3
bbb: 2
ccc: 4
```

Comment: я бы заменил List на HahSet, чтобы значения тоже не повторялись.

Comment: @tym32167 а автор вопроса желал, чтобы они не повторялись? В принципе, без проблем, сейчас добавлю.

Comment: автору вроде надо список или массив, но мне кажется, что большое опций = лушче, так как ваш ответ можно будет переиспользовать для подобных вопросов в будущем.